# How to remove some session array segment after click button in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

How can I do this. Please help me.

This is my controller function

```
public function payment_plan() {

    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->status = FALSE;
    $post_data = $this->input->post();
    if ($post_data) {
        $payment_plan = $post_data['payment_plan'];
        $value = $post_data['value'];

        $deleted_plan = $this->input->post('key');

        $payment_plans = $payment_plan."/".$value.",";            

        $payment_session = $this->session->userdata('payment_plans');
        if($payment_session == NULL){
            $array_one = array();
            array_push($array_one, $payment_plans);
            $this->session->set_userdata('payment_plans', $array_one);
        }  else {
           $session_two=  $this->session->userdata('payment_plans');
           array_push($session_two, $payment_plans);               
           $this->session->set_userdata('payment_plans', $session_two);
        }

        $final_session = $this->session->userdata('payment_plans');

        $this->data['payment_plans'] = $final_session;
        //var_dump($final_session);
        $result->status = TRUE;
        $this->load->view('cms/payment_plan', $this->data);
    }
}
```

If I clicked delete button in view page `$deleted_plan` fill via jQuery.

This is my jQuery code

```
$(".key").click(function () {

    var key = $(this).attr('id');        

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "property" + "/" + "payment_plan",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {key: key,payment_plan: payment_plan, value: value},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                // $("#payment_plans").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is how I remove array segments in session array after I clicked Delete button.

Comment: you can user on click event in function $this->session->unset_userdata('session_name');

Comment: if I use  $this->session->unset_userdata('session_name'); all array element unset

Comment: can you please write your sample session array and desire session result here ?

Comment: First store the session in a variable then Try splicing the array to remove  key posted and than overwriting the session with the desired spliced array.

Comment: Based on your code, what you are really doing is you are adding to session variable the plan that is deleted. Every time `$payment_plans` is pushed using array_push(), you are adding the deleted plan in the session. This is assuming that the 'key', 'payment_plan' & 'value' that are sent in POST are for the deleted plan.

The condition `$payment_session == NULL` means that there are no payment plans set in session. If that is the case, then there wouldn't be anything available to delete. So I don't think that condition will ever be satisfied.

The `$deleted_plan` variable is unsed. Reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, hope it'll help

```
if($deleted_plan)
{
    foreach($final_session as $k => $session)
    {
         if(isset($session[$deleted_plan]))
         {
            unset($final_session[$k][$deleted_plan]);
         }
    }
    $final_session = array_values($final_session);
    $this->session->set_userdata('payment_plans', $final_session);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below example :

Lets `take an array and set in session` like

```
$array_one = array(0=>'plan1',1=>'plan2',2=>'plan3');
$this->session->set_userdata('payment_plans', $array_one);
```

Now to unset specific element, First `get session into a variable like here $arra`

```
$arra = $this->session->userdata('payment_plans');
```

`Unset specific array element` you want to unset like if you want to `remove 'plan1'`

```
unset($arra[0]); //0 is key of plan1
```

`Set result array into session` again

```
$this->session->set_userdata('payment_plans', $arra);
$arra = $this->session->userdata('payment_plans');                
print_r($arra);
```

OR

You can directly unset session element using

```
$array_one = array(0=>'plan1',1=>'plan2',2=>'plan3');
$this->session->set_userdata('payment_plans', $array_one); //set session
unset($_SESSION['payment_plans'][0]); //unset specific element. 0 is key of session array
$arra = $this->session->userdata('payment_plans');  // get session array              
print_r($arra); // display session array
```